# Where to put CSS3 media queries?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am having a philosophical debate with myself over the best place to put media queries within style sheets.  I am attempting to structure my CSS modularly (like OOCSS or SMACSS, etc). Given that context, I see two choices:

1. Put all media queries together in a separate stylesheet or section of the main stylesheet.
2. Put media queries below their base counterparts. For example, if I have a module called "news-item", I could put any necessary media query styles right below the definition of that module.

I am leaning towards the latter, but it would mean I'd have many more separate media queries (separate ones for each logical block of CSS requiring a responsive adjustment).

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

How about using media queries just to load device specific stylesheets

like:

```
@import url(mydevice.css) this and (that);
```

or:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only this and (that)" href="mydevice.css" />
```

...if you're looking at the device specific adjustments as a kind of "subthemes" to a main layout (just overwriting some properties), this would make sense to me, too.

Comment: I'm sure I read somewhere that this approach is a lot slower than having the media queries in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach #2** works better for me.

When I was a newbie, I was using **Approach #1** - I was writing my media queries together (at the bottom of my stylesheet or in another file).

```
.header { ... }
.news-item { ... }
.footer { ... }

/**
 * ...
 *
 * bla bla, imagine a huge amount of styles here
 *
 * ...
 */

/** All style tweaks for screens < 1024px */
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .header { ... }
  .news-item { ... }
}
```

This approach has a few downsides. Based on my experience, the most notable one is that **the maintainability is a hard**. The main reason: `.news-item` logic is spread across multiple unrelated lines of CSS.

Later on, naturally, I decided to keep the related styles together. **Approach #2**:

```
/** Header's styles and media queries */
.header {
  ...
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .header { ... }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .header { ... }
}

/** News-item's styles and media queries */
.news-item {
  ...
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .news-item { ... }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .news-item { ... }
}

/** ... and so on */
```

However, in this approach, repeating media queries `max-width` values all-around doesn’t look maintainable enough. I solved this issue by using a CSS pre-processor (like SASS) that allows me to replace all them with variables and define them once.

To boost up the maintainability and to make these definitions a lot more elegant I started to use an abstraction on top of the Media Queries.

If you're interested in more details, please [read on my blog post](https://medium.com/@superKalo/journey-to-highly-effective-and-maintainable-css-media-queries-876e5b92f918) :-)

Answer (score 0):

With Sass it's easier to use the media queries directly below the counterparts. But if your CSS is well commented in your modules, I don't see a problem to put the queries bellow since that would be easy to find.

You'll end up writing a little more code retyping the queries, but not a big deal.